# Replacing a value in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to handle invalid objects in JSON using Jackson 2 processor? Considering below response

```
"person":{
"name":"person name",
"age":{
      "@xsi:nil" : "true"
    },
"address":{
      "@xsi:nil" : "true"
    }
}
```

in this age and address parameters are number and string types respectively. During `null` the backend produces a sub object which we need to ignore and treat them as `null` while consuming.

I think of fix with one of the below

- Get the whole response as string and do a regex replace for `{"@xsi:nil" : "true"}` to `null`
- Introduce individual deserializers for string, number and handle them with JSON nodes.

I would like to know the best approach to handle this. Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your deserialization Java code?

Comment: I have extended StdScalarDeserializer<String> and in deserialize() method introduced the block  if ((t == JsonToken.START_OBJECT)){
         JsonToken  nxt = p.nextToken();
         while( nxt != JsonToken.END_OBJECT){
          nxt = p.nextToken();
         }
         return null;
        }

Comment: This can be like an extension for `JsonParser` to return `JsonToken.NULL_VALUE` when your `nil` pattern encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Jackson `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation at class level like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

Or use an `ObjectMapper` and configure it to ignore unkown properties:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

You can read [**Jackson Unmarshalling JSON with Unknown Properties**](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties) for further reading.

Comment: I have already tried this, the FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES will work on properties of the mapped object not on value of the property.